# Как отменить ввод с клавиатуры?

Tags: javascript

Как в определенный момент не считывать нажатие на клавиатуру?

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) { // поймать событие нажатия кнопки
    if( e.keyCode === 27 ) { // esc
        e.preventDefault(); // отменить действие
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо,теперь стоит вопрос как бы это впихнуть.